# Can Looping Through a Function "Too Fast" Break It (Node.js)

Tags: arrays, node.js, for-loop, accumulate

I am trying to accumulate API responses on a server and return them to the client as a single object.  To do this I am looping through items in an array and mapping the responses back into the original object.  This is working fine for an array of length 1, but logs blanks when looping through larger arrays.

When looping through the array does Node create a new instance of the function or does it keep passing data into the same function even if it hasn't returned a value yet?

```
loopThroughArray(req, res) { 
  for(let i=0; i<req.map.length; i++) {
    stack[i] = (callback) => {
      let data = getApi(req, res, req.map[i], callback)
    }
  }

  async.parallel(stack, (result) => {
      res.json(result)
  })
}
```

....

```
function getApi(req, res, num, cb) {
  request({
    url: 'https://example.com/api/' + num
  },
  (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
      // Log error
    } else {
      let i = {
        name: JSON.parse(body)['name'],
        age: '100'
      }
      console.log(body) // Returns empty value array.length > 1 (req.map[i])
      cb(i)
    }
  })
```

If Node is overloading the function, how can I ensure data has been received before running the function again?

Comment: You are not sending any callback.

Comment: I updated the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api calls are async.

When running the loop, the code is making many rest calls without waiting for the answer.

If the loop is not too big then you could synchronize the calls using recursion.

You could also synchronize the calls using nimble:

http://caolan.github.io/nimble/

Comment: I have a version of this code that is synchronous with recursion, but I am trying to speed it up by making it more parallel.

Comment: Node is asynchronous by nature @matthew. You should avoid making synchronous calls whenever possible in Node

Comment: The function is not returning a json because is async. You could read the json value returned by the api call using a callback

Comment: Won't the `console.log` in the `getApi` function body run synchronously?

Comment: @EvanBechtol Yes... I am trying to improve the code, but am not sure why the function isn't returning a JSON object as expected.

Comment: @MartínZaragoza The `console.log` inside the `getApi` block is not returning anything...

Comment: Oh i see... What is the response code? (is it 200 or 204 ... ?)

Comment: @MartínZaragoza For array of length 2 I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` logged out.  If I comment out the JSON parsing it will return only the second array items meta data with response code 200.

Answer (score -1):

a loop waits for the method inside it to finish before it loop back. so there's really no such thing as a loop that moves really fast unless you're using "threading" which your obviously not.

Comment: this is wrong. Rest calls are async using node. The loop does not wait for the body to complete the call

Comment: in simple term its running two loops at the "exact" same time.